# cygwin mpicxx not found

Tags: cygwin, mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to use `mpicxx` with `cygwin`. I've installed all `openmpi` packages available but when typing `mpicxx` still get a *"command not found"*. I looked into the `/usr/bin` folder and `mpicxx` is missing, while C and fortran versions are there. Any possible explanation or solution?

Comment: If you're certain you've installed a cygwin package that contains that binary, then I supposed you're getting the error because it's landed in a directory outside your PATH. I would either consult the documentation for the cygwin package that contains the executable in question, or figure out if you can obtain that compiler in any other way (e.g.compiling from source). There are some tutorials on getting mpixx to run in cygwin off-site ([example](https://sjbyrnes.com/LAMMPStutorial.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow is for programming question not for support.

Cygwin support requests should be sent to the Cygwin mailing list
https://cygwin.com/cygwin/lists.html

This particular question was already asked and the answer is at
https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-09/msg00180.html

> mpic++ and mpicxx are just links to opal_wrapper.exe you can reinstate
>   by yourself

It is the same for all the other compilers

```
$ cd /bin
$ ls -l mpi*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Marco Kein  16 Sep 13 12:17 mpic++ -> opal_wrapper.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Marco Kein 18K Mar 19  2018 mpicalc.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Marco Kein  16 Sep  5 16:46 mpicc -> opal_wrapper.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Marco Kein  11 Sep  5 16:46 mpiexec -> orterun.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Marco Kein  16 Sep  5 16:46 mpif77 -> opal_wrapper.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Marco Kein  16 Sep  5 16:46 mpif90 -> opal_wrapper.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Marco Kein  16 Sep  5 16:46 mpifort -> opal_wrapper.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Marco Kein  11 Sep  5 16:46 mpirun -> orterun.exe
```